# Loop through JSON response using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am making an API request via *PHP cURL*.

When I run `echo $response` I get the following JSON:

**JSON (application/json):**

```
{
    "workers": [
        {
            "email": "micky@mcgurk.com",
            "manager": {
                "email": "boss@mcgurk.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": "michelle@mcgurk.com",
            "manager": {
                "email": "another_boss@mcgurk.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to loop through the results & echo out the email and associated manager. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "workers": [
        {
            "email": "micky@mcgurk.com",
            "manager": {
                "email": "boss@mcgurk.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": "michelle@mcgurk.com",
            "manager": {
                "email": "another_boss@mcgurk.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}';
$dec = json_decode($json);
$users = array();
if (! empty($dec->workers)) {
    foreach ($dec->workers as $worker) {
        $user['email'] = $worker->email;
        $user['manager_email'] = $worker->manager->email;
        $users[] = $user;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($users);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => micky@mcgurk.com
            [manager_email] => boss@mcgurk.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => michelle@mcgurk.com
            [manager_email] => another_boss@mcgurk.com
        )

)
```

Now, loop over `$dec->workers` and you will get the required email addresses.

Comment: Hi @Pupil - this is great! I'm looking to insert these into a table in my database. Instead of `print_r($dec->employees);` - is there a way to loop through (foreach?) and output each row in a line?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, answer updated. Please verify.

Comment: Is it something like `foreach ($dec->workers as &$value) {echo $value['email'];}`?

Comment: Thank you so much, Pupil. That is incredibly helpful. Thanks for your patience here too. I have learned a lot today :-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, nothing special about. When I was a neophyte, people helped me to learn. This is the way we grow. :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Look into json_decode()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

The result will be an associative array (or object) that you can iterate through

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, Eriks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```